# In neo4j community, how does neo4j DB parse a Cypher statement whether it is CREATE, UPDATE or DELETE？

Tags: neo4j

I'm watching the neo4j source code from github, but I can't find out what code is involved in parsing the Cypher statement, can anyone help me?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are searching this ?

Comment: I want to achieve HA in community version. So first of all, when a cypher comes to DB, I need to know whether this cypher  want to CREATE、UPDATE or DELETE。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side you can determine whether the transaction is read or write transaction by calling appropriate method on the `Session` object:

```
session.writeTransaction( new TransactionWork<Void>()
    {
        @Override
        public Void execute( Transaction tx )
        {
            ...
        }
    } );
return session.readTransaction( new TransactionWork<Long>()
    {
        @Override
        public Long execute( Transaction tx )
        {
            ...
        }
    } );
```

This is mainly used to determine if a query can go to a read replica in causal cluster. See the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/1.7/sessions-transactions/#driver-transactions-access-mode) for details.

If you are looking for internal db implementation you should look around the [KernelTransactionImplementation](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.5.9/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/api/KernelTransactionImplementation.java#L678) class.

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm looking for the internal implementation. but I can't find any code about the DB analyzing the type of cypher statement.....I'll continue to try it....

Comment: Just to clarify, the driver code cited here is what the programmer will write to signal to the driver that this is a read or write transaction so it can route accordingly. There is no implicit parsing going on at the driver level to figure out if the query is read or write, as that would require the driver to include code for Cypher parsing, and would require the driver to keep up with new Cypher implementations. We don't want to have that kind of coupling or have a design which requires parsing the query twice, once on the client and another on the server.